# Excel - initial and final values are known, how to generate the random number in between in descending order?

Tags: excel

In Excel, I want to generate 1000 rows of values, I only know the initial and final values.

For example, cell a1=0.6 and cell a1000=0.2, I want the values in between to reduce slowly where they does not need to reduce in the same amount (random amount) from each row to another row as long as it fulfills the initial and final values and the change is in descending order?

Any idea how could I create a formula to achieve this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's reasonably possible to do this with a single formula, copied down for all 998 rows between the two numbers, I don't think it would give the desired result. Instead, I would do it in three steps:

1. Calculate a random number between those two numbers with a formula:
    `=(RAND()*0.4)+0.2` and copy from row 2 down to 999
2. Copy column `A` and Paste Special>>Values over the top of itself
3. Sort the list in ascending order.

Comment: Thank you very much, this will generate a series of linear numbers as desired. May I ask if it is possible to generate exponential growth instead of linear? Thanks

Comment: You'll have to get quite a bit craftier to get something that is random, yet fits to an exponential regression. You could start with an exponential regression formula that uses `=ROW()` to come up with a number between `.2` and `.6` and then add some randomness to it. Something like: `= 0.2*(EXP(.0011*((ROW()-1)+(-50 + (RAND()*100)))))` That's the formula `.2e^(.0011*(ROW()-1))` but with a random bit thrown in there to add some variance. Because this will add +/- a bit as it climbs the rows, you'll need to copy/pastespecial and sort to get them in order again.

Answer (score 1):

With data in *Sheet1*, run macro *dural*:

```
Sub dural()
  Dim v1 As Double, v1000 As Double
  v1 = Range("A1").Value
  v1000 = Range("A1000").Value
  Randomize
  For i = 2 To 999
    Cells(i, "A").Value = Rnd * (v1 - v1000) + v1000
  Next i

  Call SortData
End Sub

Sub SortData()
    Columns("A:A").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:A1000")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]